# Can HP 2209t monitor detect multi-touch like HP TouchSmart monitor?

Tags: display, touchsmart

I know you can help me out from this little problem.

I am planing to buy a monitor with multi-touch feature that I can use to develop multi-touch application in Windows 7. I found HP provide them already, TouchSmart 300 and TouchSmart 600 series, but the hardware that combined in package is too low performance.

So I am looking for just multi-touch monitor and I found [HP 2209t](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/hk/en/ho/WF06b/382087-382087-3284302-215012-215012-3739209-4073228.html) Touch monitor. but in the specification they provided, does not describe "it can multi-touch" so could you help me by give your advice to me here?

I also think that there's more model that can use multi-touch in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked up the manual http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01951805/c01951805.pdf

p15 says it can multi touch in windows 7

Comment: Thank you very much, Steve! You are the only one who really help me out. Thank you.